# nlp.js - TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLanguage' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, nlp, command-line-interface

I'm trying to use nlp.js in my node cli script. I've implemented the basic example provided here but when I run my script I get this error

```js
nlp.addLanguage('en');
      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLanguage' of undefined
```

This is the code I have in my `index.js` file, it's the same of basic example provided but on my machine will not work

```js
const { dockStart } = require('@nlpjs/basic');

(async () => {
  const dock = await dockStart({ use: ['Basic']});
  const nlp = dock.get('nlp');
  //console.log(dock, nlp);
  nlp.addLanguage('en');
  // Adds the utterances and intents for the NLP
  nlp.addDocument('en', 'goodbye for now', 'greetings.bye');
  nlp.addDocument('en', 'bye bye take care', 'greetings.bye');
  nlp.addDocument('en', 'okay see you later', 'greetings.bye');
  nlp.addDocument('en', 'bye for now', 'greetings.bye');
  nlp.addDocument('en', 'i must go', 'greetings.bye');
  nlp.addDocument('en', 'hello', 'greetings.hello');
  nlp.addDocument('en', 'hi', 'greetings.hello');
  nlp.addDocument('en', 'howdy', 'greetings.hello');
  
  // Train also the NLG
  nlp.addAnswer('en', 'greetings.bye', 'Till next time');
  nlp.addAnswer('en', 'greetings.bye', 'see you soon!');
  nlp.addAnswer('en', 'greetings.hello', 'Hey there!');
  nlp.addAnswer('en', 'greetings.hello', 'Greetings!');  
  await nlp.train();
  const response = await nlp.process('en', 'I should go now');
  console.log(response);
})();
```

I've tried to `console.log` the `dock` and the `nlp` variables, while `dock` is defined, `nlp` will be always undefined but I don't know why. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: FYI, I just tested this on my machine and it works fine. Sorry that's not much help.

Comment: @Andy what is yout envoirment? I'm on macOS 10.13.6 with node16.0.0 installed. This is the only library I'm using that not working as expected

Comment: Windows, v15.8.

Comment: not sure if the problem is caused by node v16 :(

Comment: I'll upgrade and let you know what happens. Hang on.

Comment: ok, thank you. I'm thinking to install nvm and node 14 to test if the issue will solev but not sure because into the repo issues there is nothing similar to my problem

Comment: Node 16.1. It still works.

Comment: have you installed the library node-nlp or the one suggested from the documentations?

Comment: The one from the documentation: nlp/basic

Comment: I'm updating node to 16.1 I hope to solve the problem

Comment: @QuatbanTaco no